# How to send a state into child component as dataset of D3.js object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I'm working on a web project, which provides a user-friendly interface includes a data viz object.

It is my first time to use React and D3 together to design main function, and some problems happened in data processing. I write D3 part first.

```
class ObjectD3 extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.myRef = React.createRef();
        this.dataset = _____ ;

componentDidMount(){
      // D3 Code 
}

render(){
        return( <div ref ={this.myRef}></div> );
        }
```

When I put original `JSON` data in `this.dataset`, it works. Now I want to build filter function, the D3 object will change when filter button is triggered.

Ideal data flow would be:

1. Original JSON local file
2. `getCompany()`
3. `filterCompany()`
4. `Filter()` (Function component state)  & `setFiltredCompany`
5. `ObjectD3`

The flow works before step 5, the dataset I need is stored in the state of `Filter()` properly.

```
console.log(filtredCompany)
// {filtredCompany: Array(923)}
```

At step 5, I can't pass the `filtredCompany` to `ObjectD3`. I try to send `props` but fail.

```
// Filter.js  
<ObjectD3 outputFilter = {filtredCompany} />

// ObjectD3
 this.dataset = this.props.outputFilter
```

And it turns out:

```
TypeError: svgCanvus.append(...).selectAll(...).data(...).join(...).attr is not a function
```

The error doesn't happen when I used the local JSON file. It seems strange, because `this.props.outputFilter` and local JSON file are the same. I guess problem might be

1. `this.dataset = this.props.outputFilter` is not vaild.
2. render problems

Attatched source code below. Does anyone know how to handle this situation or better idea to pass data? Thank you so much in advanced!

```
// Services.js

import _ from "lodash";
import { Companies } from "./data";

export function getCompany() {
  const companyList = fullCom;
  return companyList;
}

export function filterCompany(comType) {
  // details of filter
  
  let filtredMatchCompany = getCompany().filter(type => type.SDGs === comType && type.No == comType);
  let companyList = getCompany();

  let matchCom = _.map(filtredMatchCompany, 'ComName');
  let filtredCompany = companyList.filter((type)=> matchCom.includes(type.ComName))

  return filtredCompany;
}
```

```
// Filter.js

import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { buttons } from "./data";
import { getCompany, filterCompany } from "./services";

export default function Filter() {
  const [filtredCompany,setFiltredCompany] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setFiltredCompany(getCompany());
  }, []);
  
  function handleD3(e) {
    let typeCompany = e.target.value;
    typeCompany !== "all"
      ? setFiltredCompany(filterCompany(typeCompany))
      : setFiltredCompany(getCompany()); 
  }

  const outputFilter = filtredCompany;

  return (
    <>
      {buttons &&
        buttons.map((type, series) => (
          <>
              <button key={series} value={type.no} onClick={handleD3}>
                  {type.name}
              </button>
          </>
        ))}
          <>
             <ObjectD3 outputFilter = {filtredCompany}/>
          </>
   </>
}
```

*update D3 code*

```
// ObjectD3

import React from 'react';
import * as d3 from 'd3';

class ObjectD3 extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.myRef = React.createRef();
        this.dataset = this.props.outputFilter;
    }

    componentDidMount(){

        const margin = {top:30, right:30, bottom:30, left:30};
        const width = 2000;
        const height = 2000;
        const innerRadius = 80;
        const outerRadius = Math.min(width, height)/2;

        const svgCanvus = d3.select(this.myRef.current)
            .append('svg')
                .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                
            .append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + ( height/2+10 )+ ")");

        const myGroups = comName
        const myVars = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17"]
        
        let x = d3.scaleBand()
            .range([ 0, 2 * Math.PI ])
            .domain(myGroups)
            .padding(0.5);
      
        let y = d3.scaleBand()
            .range([ outerRadius, innerRadius ])
            .domain(myVars)
            .padding(0);

        const tColor = d3.scaleOrdinal().domain(myVars)
                         .range(["#E5243B","#DDA63A","#4C9F38","#C5192D","#FF3A21","#26BDE2","#FCC30B","#A21942","#FD6925","#DD1367","#FD9D24","#BD882E","#3F7E44","#0A97D9","#56C02B","#00689D","#19486A"])

// Here's where TypeError message occurs. It works fine when `this.dataset = localJSON` 
        
        svgCanvus.append("g").selectAll("path")
                .data(this.dataset)
                .join("path")
                .attr("d", d3.arc()
                    .innerRadius(innerRadius)
                    .outerRadius(function(d) { return y(d.SDGs) })
                    .startAngle(function(d) { return x(d.ComName) })
                    .endAngle(function(d) { return x(d.ComName) + x.bandwidth(); })
                    .padAngle(0)
                    .padRadius(innerRadius))
                    .style("fill", function(d) { 
                        if (d.No === 0) {return "white"}
                        else {return tColor(d.No)}
                        });
                        
        }
                    
        render(){
            return(
                <div ref ={this.myRef}></div>
                
            );
        }
```

Comment: Your question is difficult to understand. Please describe more carefully your data flow like (__1.__ Set state to `x` __2.__ The effect `y` is trigered __3.__ The data `z` is changed) and so on...

Comment: Hi Michael, thank you for your suggestion. I updated my question, please let me know if there is something not clear.

Comment: Why do you assign `const outputFilter = filtredCompany;` and then call `<ObjectA outputFilter = {outputFilter}/>` instead of simply pass __filtredCompany__ to __ObjectA__: `<ObjectA outputFilter = {filtredCompany}/>` ?

Comment: I fixed that typo and update the TypeError message. I'm not sure what the problem is: `ObjectA` doesn't receive data, or render problem.

Comment: Hi Michael, I update the few discussion to my post. Thank for your kind review!

Comment: Where is the code that generates the error `svgCanvus.append(...` ?

Comment: in ObjectD3, I have updated the code. It might be little messy, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will not work:

```
svgCanvus.append("g").selectAll("path")
                .data(this.dataset)
                .join("path")
                .attr("d", d3.arc()
                    .innerRadius(innerRadius)
                    .outerRadius(function(d) { return y(d.SDGs) })
                    .startAngle(function(d) { return x(d.ComName) })
                    .endAngle(function(d) { return x(d.ComName) + x.bandwidth(); })
                    .padAngle(0)
                    .padRadius(innerRadius))
                    .style("fill", function(d) { 
                        if (d.No === 0) {return "white"}
                        else {return tColor(d.No)}
                        });
```

You need to pass **d** properly:

```js
const arcPath = d => d3.arc()
  .innerRadius(innerRadius)
  .outerRadius(y(d.SDGs))
  .startAngle(x(d.ComName))
  .endAngle(x(d.ComName) + x.bandwidth())
  .padAngle(0)
  .padRadius(innerRadius);
  
svgCanvus.append("g").selectAll("path")
  .data(this.dataset)
  .join("path")
  .attr("d", d => arcPath(d)()) 
  .style("fill", d => d.No === 0 ? 'white' : tColor(d.No));
```

Comment: After replacing these code, it turns out TypeErrror. 
`svgCanvus.append(...).selectAll(...).data(...).join(...).attr is not a function`

Comment: Which version of D3 do you use?

Comment: Replace the last line with `.attr("d", d => arcPath(d)())` (as in the updated answer). Does it help?

Comment: Still the same TypeError here. I use D3 v5.16.0 for tooltip library compatibility. Should I update to v6?

Comment: Yes. Please upgrade to V6 and let me know if the problem persists

Comment: It turns out `TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in null` 

`(anonymous function)
node_modules/d3/node_modules/d3-selection/src/array.js:2`

ObjectD3.componentDidMount

`svgCanvus.append("g").selectAll("path")`

Comment: Well, it seems to be a totally unrelated problem... Try to comment out parts of your code one by one until the error disappears.

Comment: I fixed that unrelated problem and upgrade D3 again (now v6.7.0). There's still TypeError in D3 part, `d3__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.arc(...).innerRadius(...).outerRadius(...).startAngle(...).endAngle(...).padAngle(...).padRadius(...).style is not a function`

Comment: From the `const arcPath = d => d3.arc()...` statement, comment off from `.innerRadius(...` to `.style(...` (leave `const arcPath = d => d3.arc()` alone). Still having the same error?

Comment: It becomes `TypeError : Cannot read property 'innerRadius' of undefined`

Comment: Ok, we having a progress here... Now start adding the lines to the statement one by one, until you get back the original error (not a function)

Comment: Well, the original error finally occurs when I adding all the code back. btw I take away the last close parenthesis in your answer  `.padRadius(innerRadius))` to avoid typo error at the beginning.

Comment: OK, great. Now add the following statement: `const test = arcPath(this.dataset[0])()`; do you get any error?

Comment: `console.log(d3.arc())` what do you see?

Comment: seems like a function. `ƒ arc() {var buffer, r, r0 = +innerRadius.apply(this, arguments), r1 = +outerRadius.apply(this, arguments), a0 = startAngle.apply(this, arguments) - _math_js__WEBPA…`

Comment: I've just tested this code `console.log(
  d3.arc()
    .startAngle(Math.PI / 2)
    .endAngle(Math.PI)
    .innerRadius(10)
    .outerRadius(20)());` in a fiddle with D3 v.5.9.2 and everything works fine. There is somethin wrong with the D3 version you have!

Comment: Try to run the code from my last comment in your project

Comment: One more thing: move the line `.style(...` to the second statement (just like in the answer)

Comment: After moving `.style(...`, TypeError becomes `Cannot read property 'SDGs' of undefined
(anonymous function)`. Besides, now D3 version in the project is v6.7.0, and D3.arc() works when (1) I use local JSON file, not filtred one (2) before code was modified

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231872/discussion-between-michael-rovinsky-and-vikky-huang).